# Help me find the implied monthly interest rate please

Tags: finance

Your friend Zoe is planning to buy an outdoor patio set from a furniture store. The MSRP (the marked price) \$9600  and the seller offers a zero-interest financing plan which allows buyers to pay $400 per month over 24 months, starting one month from now. However, the seller also tells Zoe that if she pays the price in full right now, she could get a 10% discount off the marked price.

Comment: what have you tried? We are not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: I don't know which formula to use

Comment: How much is 10% from 9600$?

Comment: 10% of 9600 is $960

Comment: Is this a Mathematica question? You can go about this multiple ways : `Annuity`, `TimeValue`, and `EffectiveInterest` may all be useful. The seller is offering a 10% discount (8640) today in full, but expects 9600 after 24 months if Zoe uses the payment plan. So at what interest rate will 8640 compound over 24 months to become 9600 ? You need to solve 8640 * (1+(r/100))^24 == 9600. The interest rate represents how much more valuable the seller's money is today than in 24-months - the present value vs. future value.